# How do I pass a parameter from a form_for to a different controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an Issue model and a Comment model. On the issue#show view, I have a comment form. I create the @comment for the form in the issue#show controller action, and then pass it to the comment#create controller action to actually create and save the comment to the db. However, once the @comment params are passed to the comment#create action, I no longer have the issue_id information that I need. How would I pass that information? Here are my files:

```
<%= form_for @comment do |f| %>
    <%= render 'comment_fields', :f => f %>
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

issue controller:

```
  def show
     @issue = Issue.find(params[:id])
     @votes = Votership.where(:issue_id => @issue.id)
     @current_user_vote = @votes.where(:user_id => current_user.id).first
     @comment = Comment.new
  end
```

and the comment controller:

```
  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
    @comment.save
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to modify the way you create your `@comment` in the `show` action

```
def show
  @issue = Issue.find(params[:id])
  @votes = Votership.where(:issue_id => @issue.id)
  @current_user_vote = @votes.where(:user_id => current_user.id).first
  @comment = @issue.comments.build # assigns issue_id to comment
end
```

Now when you render the form for `@comment`, the `issue_id` should be present in the hidden form inputs

---

This is unrelated to your question, but I'm also noticing the way you're loading `@current_user_vote`

```
@current_user_vote = @votes.where(:user_id => current_user.id).first
```

You should probably do this as:

```
@current_user_vote = current_user.votes.first
```

Comment: I tried something like this by creating the comment for the issues#show view and it contained the proper variable I needed. However, when it got passed to the comments#create action, when I did Comment.new(params[:comment]) it deleted that variable (I believe because it created a new Comment and didn't contain that var in the params[:comment]). When I tried your code, build_comment gave me an error: undefined method `build_comment'

Comment: version 3.1...all I need is a way to pass issue_id to my comments controller. I almost got it working by passing a hidden field with it like so: <%= hidden_field(:issue_id, @issue.id) %> however, I don't think i implemented this right because it is passing a has called issue_id with key = @issue.id and value = nil.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, an issue may have many comments and a comment belongs to an issue?

```
# config/routes.rb
# Nest the comment under the issue
resources :issues do
  resources :comments, only[:create]
end

# app/models/issue.rb
has_many :comments

# app/models/comment.rb
belongs_to :issue

# app/controllers/issues_controller.rb
def show
  @issue = Issue.find params[:id]
  ...
end

# app/views/issues/show.html.erb
<%= form_for [@issue, @issue.comments.build] do |f| %>
....
<% end %>

# app/controllers/comments_controller.rb
def create
  @issue = Issue.find params[:issue_id]
  @comment = @issue.comments.build params[:comment]
  if @comment.save
    redirect_to @issue
  else
    render 'issues/show' # => it will know which issue you are talking about, don't worry
  end
end

# or if you don't need validation on comment:
def create
  @issue = Issue.find params[:issue_id]
  @issue.comments.create params[:comment]
  redirect_to @issue
end
```

issues#show a little bit looks weird.

```
def show
  @issue = Issue.find params[:id]
  @votes = @issue.voterships
  @current_user_vote = current_user.votes.first
  # maybe you want to list all the comments: @comments = @issue.comments
end
```

Comment: yes, but I don't have a resource for comments...it isn't needed. this doesn't work

Comment: I added in a resource for that. However, comments belong to issues belong to apps. so there is a double nested resource. how would I do it in that case?

Comment: but how do i use the rest of the code you suggested knowing i need app/issue/comment